# laptop to external monitor via vga cable not working

Tags: gnome, monitor, vga

My laptop is the Toshiba satellite c850-F31Q (with these specs:http://www.laptopdirect.co.za/laptop_specifications.php?laptop=59683)(AMD Radeon graphics card).

It is running Linux-Ubuntu-gnome 3 (and Windows 7; dual boot)

Urgently need to know how to connect it via VGA  to -

External LG monitor (works great in Windows).

Please could you help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the display settings, and make sure that the second monitor is not turned off, and that "Mirror Displays" is not checked.

[image]

Comment: My laptop does not recognize the external monitor (equivalent to only the pink box in the image you provided). WOuld I need to download a driver to make my laptop detect the monitor?

Comment: What is your monitor's model number?

Comment: hi el7r it is a LG Flatron W1943SS .... Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: also I just tried this website for drivers http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx but my laptop refuses to install it (I dont know how to run it through terminal commands so I havent tried to do it that way)

Answer (score 0):

Press the function key and switch from lcd to screen (you will see a symbol on your keyboard) this applies if you are using a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ton install proprietary drivers? this is how you do that:

go to system settings, now click 'Software & Updates' go to the 'additional drivers' tab.
here you should be able to select one or more drivers for your card.

however...

In the little experience with ATI cards I think the proprietary drivers are not always stable. prepare for some trouble shouting and back up all your files (if you cannot boot anymore you can in case of emergency reinstall).